# How to run a promotion in the Android Market

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know how to run a promotional price in the Android Market?

I swear I have seen apps on the market with a prices slashed through with a temporary price (like 33% off, etc).

Am I crazy and there is no way to do this or what?  I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can lower the price of your app in the Android Market to promote it, but there is currently no way to display it with the old price slashed through.

You probably saw the slashed through prices on other market sites (eg http://www.appbrain.com), which monitor the market and show a changelog for each app. (including old prices)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the app's properties through the developer console, which includes the pricing

Comment: Yes you can modify the price (down to .99).  But that is not what I am referring to.

Comment: Then what are you referring to? Screen shot, example, etc. Are you sure they didn't just change the price and put in the description "Today only 33% off !!!"

Comment: You might be right Fraggle.  I'm going to try and scout the market to see if I can find one.